# Explanation of ++val++ and ++*p++ in C

Tags: c, increment, operator-precedence

```
int val = 5;

printf("%d",++val++); //gives compilation error : '++' needs l-value

int *p = &val;
printf("%d",++*p++); //no error
```

Could someone explain these 2 cases? Thanks.

Comment: In cases like this, it often helps to also post the error messages you're seeing and the compiler (version) you're using.

Comment: No one should ever write code like this.

Comment: Vote to close as not a real question. Code like this is not found in real life. Anything that is just an accident of syntax like this should be pointed to the a FAQ that just says don't be silly.

Comment: @Martin: and if you do find code like this in real life, fix it and then slap the person responsible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`++val++` is the same as `++(val++)`. Since the result of `val++` is not an lvalue, this is illegal. And as Stephen Canon pointed out, if the result of `val++` were an lvalue, `++(val++)` would be undefined behavior as there is no sequence point between the `++`s.

`++*p++` is the same as `++(*(p++))`. Since the result of `*(p++)` *is* an lvalue, this is legal.

Comment: Excellent answer, though I would note that that even if `val++` were an lvalue, the behavior would still be undefined.  `(++val)++` in C++, for example, would invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Post-increment operator always returns an `rvalue`(in C as well as in C++). In C++, `(++val)++` invokes Undefined Behavior because pre-increment(`++`) operator returns an lvalue(in C++) and the value of `val` is being modified more than once between two sequence points.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `++val++` is the same as `(++val)++` (or perhaps `++(val++)`, anyway it's not very relevant). The result of the `++` operator is not the variable, but the value, and you can't apply the operator to a value.

The expression `++*p++` is the same as `++(*(p++))`. The result of `p++` is the value, but the result of `*(p++)` is a memory location, which the `++` operator can be applied to.

Comment: `++val++` is the same as `++(val++)`, which is **not** the same as `(++val)++`.  (Though in C, both are syntactically invalid)

Comment: @Stephen Canon: Yes, it's just not obvious which one it evaluates to. As the expression is invalid I never bothered to learn which of two invalid variants it is. :)

Comment: ah, but in C++, one of them is invalid while the other is syntactically valid but semantically undefined.  (C++ is wacky!)

Answer (score 1):

also note that you're changing the address of the pointer by

```
int k = ++*p++;
```

Comment: yes I know that. I used it for simplicity. Instead of int val, I could have used int array.

Answer (score 0):

`int j = ++val++; //gives compilation error`

That because you cannot pre-increment an `rvalue`. `++val++` is interpreted as `++(val++)` because post-increment operator has higher precedence than pre-increment operator. `val++` returns an `rvalue` and pre-increment operator requires its operand to be an `lvalue`. :)

`int k = ++*p++; //no error`

`++*p++` is interpreted as `++(*(p++))`, which is perfectly valid.